# How to show a div when I scroll down on an ID in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, show

I've found a solution how to show (fade in) a DIV when I scroll down an amount of pixels, let's say 400px from the top, but how to show a DIV when I scroll down on a DIV with a specific ID? (the thing is that I don't know the height of DIVs, so that's why I am trying to implement this functionality based on IDs)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check a [offset position](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) of the element with ID and apply you example where replace static value (400px) by value from the offset.

Example:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() >= $('#selector').offset().top) {
      $('#hidden').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: But I don't know the height/position from the top. Is there any way to recognise that I scrolled down on a certain ID?

Comment: As I wrote it is offset method in jQuery object.